# How to change the text on the second activity on button clicked from first activity? [KOTLIN]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-activity

**I have to implement OTP validation on my application, I just want to get the mobile number from the previous activity and set it to the textview on the next activity once I clicked the Next Button intent from Activity 1 to Activity 2.**

Here is how it looks like in view:
[image]

**I would like to put the mobile number below the please enter the otp that has sent to..**

First try: I called the ObjectSingleton.mobileNum since it carries the mobile # then I used mobileNum.setText(ObjectSingleton.mobileNum) but it ddint work.

**My codes in 1st Activity where intent is happening to go to the next Activity;**

```
class MobileNumberActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OtpInterface.MobileNumberViews {
lateinit var presenterMobileNumber:MobileNumberPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile_number)
    presenterMobileNumber = MobileNumberPresenter()
    presenterMobileNumber.mobileViews = this
    close_icon2.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }
    nxtBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if (inputText.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            inputText.error = "Please enter valid mobile number."
        } else if (inputText.text.toString().length != 10) {
            inputText.error = "Please enter valid mobile number."
        } else{
            val mobile = inputText.text.toString()
            presenterMobileNumber.otpMobile(mobile)
        }
    }
}
override fun ifFailed(msg: String) {
    errorMsg.setText(msg)
}
override fun ifSuccess(res: OtpData) {
    errorMsg.setText("Sent!")
    var intent = Intent(this, OtpValidationActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**Here are the codes of the 2nd Acitivy where I want to change the text of mobile number display**

```
class OtpValidationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OtpValidateInterface.OtpValidateViews {
lateinit var otpPresenter: OtpPresenter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification)

    otpPresenter = OtpPresenter()
   otpPresenter.otpValidationViews = this

    verifyOtpBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if (otp_input.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            otp_input.error = "Please enter OTP."
        } else{


            val otpNumber = otp_input.text.toString()
            otpPresenter.otpValidate(ObjectSingleton.mobileNum,otpNumber)
        }
    }
}

override fun validateFailed(res: String) {
    resend.setText("Failed")
}

override fun validateSuccess(msg: OtpValidationData) {
    resend.setText("Success")



}
```

For your REFERENCE here's the XML file of the said PICTURE above where should I put the Mobile number.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/otpbg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.041">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:text="OTP VERIFICATION"
                android:textColor="@color/reply_black_800"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please enter the OTP that has sent to">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mobileNum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_22sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:text="@string/_63"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_19sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold">


            </TextView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <com.mukesh.OtpView
            android:id="@+id/otp_input"
            android:layout_width="267dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:OtpItemCount="6"
            app:OtpItemWidth="@dimen/_30sdp"
            app:OtpLineColor="@color/reply_black_800"
            app:OtpViewType="line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_19sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:text="@string/didn_t_recieve_the_code_resend_code"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otp_view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.039"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/verifyOtpBtn"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_btn"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.117" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am new to Kotlin/Android Develepment I hope someone help me with this.
#JUniorDEV

UPDATE: Imma share to you my MobileNumberPresenter codes:

```
    var mobileViews:OtpInterface.MobileNumberViews? = null
    override fun otpMobile(mobile: String) {
        Fuel.post("https://api.staging.riderko.com/riderko_be/public/api/riderSendRegisterOtp", listOf(
            "mobile" to mobile
        )).timeout(5000)
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .responseObject<OtpResponse>{request, response, result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Result.Failure -> {
                        mobileViews?.ifFailed(result.error.response.statusCode.toString())
                    }
                    is Result.Success -> {
                        val (bytes, error) = result
                        if (bytes != null) {
                            val status = bytes.success
                            if (status){
                                mobileViews?.ifSuccess(bytes.data)
                            }else{
                                mobileViews?.ifFailed(bytes.message)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this simply by calling `ObjectSingleton.mobNum` assigned to a variable and displayed it into view I just learnt that once `objectsingleton` has been assigned to, the value will be carried over to any part of your app, this value will be removed automatically when you close your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the MobileNumberActivity inside the `ifSuccess()` before you do `startActivity(intent)` do `intent.putExtra("IDENTIFER",mobileNum)`

Now in the 2nd activity simply do `val mobNO = intent.getStringExtra("IDENTIFER")`

and now assign the mobNo to the desired textView.

This helps pass data between activities.

Comment: I am getting an error when I did val mobNO = intent.getExtra("IDENTIFER") in the onCreate of 2nd activity. It seems it doesnt know who is intent.

Comment: Sorry do `getStringExtra`

Answer (score 0):

in **OtpInterface.MobileNumberViews**
add second parameter as string to ifSuccess

in **MobileNumberPresenter**

change *mobileViews?.ifSuccess(bytes.data)* to                                 *mobileViews?.ifSuccess(bytes.data, mobile)*

and you ifSuccess method will be changed to

```html
override fun ifSuccess(res: OtpData, mobileNum: String) {
    errorMsg.setText("Sent!")
    var intent = Intent(this, OtpValidationActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("MOBILE_NUMBER",mobileNum)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

And in **OtpValidationActivity**

val mobileNum = arguments?.getString("MOBILE_NUMBER")

Answer (score 0):

Update the code of 1st activity to

```
    override fun ifSuccess(res: OtpData) {
    errorMsg.setText("Sent!")
    var intent = Intent(this, OtpValidationActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    intent.putExtra("MobileNum",mobile)
}
```

Now in the second activity after setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification)
add this line:

```
val MobNo = intent.getExtra("MobileNum")
mobileNum.text = MobNo
```

Hope this will work